# Gradle Syncing error in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am new in android studio after installation I have a warning of

> Error:(13, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Anyone please Help me to solved out.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // <-- giving warning on that line
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
}
```

Comment: if you don't use any 3rd party lib in libs directory then remove it

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the libs directory.
I recommend removing that line. 
This is used to drop JARs or AAR files directly into your project. This is poor practice other then when using some of the Google Maps services.

You should reference dependencies via url and maven or ivy, not local file tree if you can avoid it.

Secondly, if you really want, you can go make a directory libs.
Lastly, I would ask how you get this error? Gradle Sync, Android Studio Build, or terminal assembleRelease.

But the above should square you away.

Comment: After created my first project I got that warning . I used maven but this warning is still there.

Comment: apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven
                { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Mushraf, I gave you steps to take, and you did not reply that you have taken these steps. I can't help you if you refuse to take my help

Comment: Sorry for that. I follow your steps. as you said to remove that line so if i remove that line then i got 3 more errors

Comment: lol. I am not able to read your mind ;). If you want help, then update your answer to show the exact error that happens when you remove that line, so we can solve the next problem